# Delete one of these Android libraries - ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21

Tags: android, macos, sdk

Under `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21` I have `default` and `google_apis`. These are roughly the same size at 3.8GB and have the same directories in each.

I'm trying to find some free space on my Mac. Can either of these be safely deleted whilst still developing Android apps?

Answer (score 0):

System images are only used to create emulators.

`google_apis` system images include Google Services like Google Maps. If you are using Google Services in your application then you will have to create an emulator with `google-apis` system image.

If you look inside `google_apis` you may find three different system images `armeabi-v7a`, `x86`, `x86_64`. You don't need all three. You can keep the one you use for creating emulator and remove others, if you do create emulator on your computer.

Once you remove one system image it will simply not show in the list where you pick image before creating one emulator.

Here's the screenshot of before and after I deleted my system image `armeabi-v7a`

Before deleting one system image `armeabi-v7a` for API 23

[image]

After deleting one system image `armeabi-v7a` for API 23

[image]